# merge columns with variable separator

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, paste, separator

I need to merge two numerical columns in my dataframe as a new column, with 0's as separators. However, the number of 0's is dependent upon the number of digits in the second column. So, what I want is something like this

```
        x     y     new 
1    12345    1    12345001
2    12345    15   12345015
3    12345    145  12345145
```

What is the proper code for this in R?

Thanks!

I'm sure it is likely some combination of paste with separators and if else statements, but I'm a rookie and can't figure it out!

Comment: Will the `new` column always have 8 digits and the `x` column will always have 5 digits?

Comment: `with(quux, sprintf("%05i%03i", x, y))` (if `quux` is your object)

Comment: @joran yes, the numer of digits in the x and new columns will always be the same, it is only the y column that varies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by utilizing R's paste0 function.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(12345, 12345, 12345),
                 y = c(1, 15, 145))

num_zeros <- nchar(max(df$y)) - nchar(df$y)

df$new <- paste0(df$x, replicate(num_zeros, "0"), df$y)

print(df)
```

If you run this code, you'll get the desired result:

```
       x   y       new
1 12345   1 123450001
2 12345  15 123450015
3 12345 145 123450145
```